# packet_write_wait Broken pipe even leaving top running?

Tags: ssh

This bloody error makes my headache going bigger and bigger everyday. I never met a same situation like this time.

Well, after I authenticated into SSH successfully, doing few stuffs then my SSH connection being dropped suddenly!!?

Here is my error message: `packet_write_wait: Connection to XXX.XX.XX.XXX: Broken pipe`

I wished my error message look like this: `Write Failed: broken pipe` a lot, believe me!

I tried a tons of resolution on the Internet like added ServerAliveInterval, ServerAliveCountMax, ClientAlive....

Someone said: Turn your TCPKeepAlive to no, added ServerAlive bllah blah idiot. I did that also but still same error.

There is no luck for me until this moment.

Any help will be appreciate.

Comment: If you are in a corporate environment, check with your firewall admins and see if they were updating rules and/or restarting the firewall after some sort of a change when this happens. If it is happening to a personal server of yours, you need to provide more information on what were you doing on the sshd server side, when this happened. `Broken pipe` generally means there was a network disconnect for some reason.

Comment: I just moved and this is happening constantly with my new connection. Cox Cable is my ISP, and I've got a Netgear C6300BD cable modem running on default settings from the install. This used to happen at my old location and I could never resolve it. It lasted for months and eventually stopped happening. I forgot how miserable and unsolvable it was until today.

Comment: I feel your pain. I came here as a last resort before I'm going to slap all my hardware into tiny little pieces. Isn't this supposed to be a fairly simple protocol?

Comment: I had the same error on Virtualized Linux, the problem solved changing the ethernet adapter to bridged

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Dear 2018 and later readers,

Let me show you a comment from MelBurslan,

> If you are in a corporate environment, check with your firewall admins and see if they were updating rules and/or restarting the firewall after some sort of a change when this happens. If it is happening to a personal server of yours, you need to provide more information on what were you doing on the sshd server side, when this happened. Broken pipe generally means there was a network disconnect for some reason.

So basically, if you are trying to use `ssh username@0.0.0.0` over a VPN (corporate environment). Then this error must be there with you over and over.

**The only solution** I found so far is [mobile-shell](https://mosh.org/). Thanks who created it.

You will need to install `mosh-server` in your target (the server you want to ssh'ed to) and `mosh-client` in your host machine.

It will auto reconnect when your packets lost, that's pretty cool and suit all our needs, I think.

**Update 03/2020:**

If you can't install `mosh-server` on your servers, then you could use my script here: https://github.com/ohmybash/oh-my-bash/blob/master/tools/autossh.sh

It will auto-reconnect to SSH automatically whenever SSH session dead.

Happy ssh'ing!

Comment: I want to SSH into an online CTF challenge account. I can't install anything on there server. What should I do?

Comment: @sh.3.ll Please check my update in answer

Answer (score 4):

I discovered it was an IPQoS option issue on my VMware Guest setup.
On the VM I set the ~/.ssh/config value for IPQoS from the default of "IPQoS af21 cs1" being low latency data for interactive first and lower effort for non-interactive for the second. Setting a new value for af21 was my solution:

```
Host *
     IPQoS throughput
```

Worked for me, otherwise yes MoSH is also worked, but mosh doesn't handling my Proxy setup in a convenient way so I stick with ProxyJump commands in

Comment: Fun, that works in the command line (as you explain in your post on ubuntu) but not in the config file 8-D

Answer (score 1):

First, make sure your issue is not related to [this one](https://askubuntu.com/a/354245).

If not and the problem is still present, read on.

I experienced this problem as well and spent a few days tried to bissect it.

Like specified, playing with SSH KeepAlive parameters or kernel TCP parameters (TCPKeepAlive on/off) does not solve the problem.

After playing with usb to ethernet drivers and TCP dump, I realized the issue was due to the kernel 4.8. I switched the source (sending side) to 4.4 LTS and the problem disappeared (rsync, scp were working nicely again). The destination side can remain on 4.8 if you want, in my use case this was working (tested).

On the technical side, we can narrow a little bit the issue thanks to the wireshark dump below I made. We can see the TCP channel of the SSHv2 protocol is being reset (RST flag of TCP set to 1) causing the connection to abort. I don't know the cause of the RST yet. I need to make some bisection from 4.8.1 to 4.8.11 for that. [image]

I'm not saying your problem is specifically due to the kernel 4.8, but wrt. the date you posted your question/message, you may have been using a kernel version which was actually buggy.

Answered initially on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41045103/3514658).

Comment: Kernel is not the problem, because I was using 4.4 LTS all the time. The real problem here was answered by @MelBursan in question's comment. My internet connection using VPN, that is why. Solution: https://mosh.org

Comment: @ToanNguyen Ok. That way, could you please put his/her comment as answer to your question and mark it as fixed? :-) If you have found the technical reasons why you needed mosh, please add them too :-). On my side, I have VPN connections as well and these were working flawlessly without mosh.

Comment: I'm getting back on this. The problem was not due to a buggy kernel, but to a buggy driver, especially the part dedicated to the hardware checksum offload. See [this thread for more info](https://linux-tips.com/t/how-to-solve-ssh-disconnect-packet-corrupt-problems/258).

Comment: Does it solve your problem?

Comment: @ToanNguyen Actually last time I had this issue I simply downgraded the kernel and it was working again. Now, I simply disabled the hw checksum offload, without downgrading anything and it solved the issue, yes.

Answer (score 1):

`ssh -o IPQoS=throughput user@{ip}`

Comment: There's no indication that the user is using macOS or that they are trying to log in as root.

Comment: Your are, right! However, I tested the command with user different than 'root' and on windows. Still works!

Answer (score 1):

Actually i found a solution to the problem, Please check your Linux users if they were mapped to your SELinux users.

let me explain, by default all user created on linux have the same unconfined_u SElinux user context, this means ordinary linux users are able to do what the root does, **an explicit change or mapping between Linux user to SElinux user could prevent ssh from working properly.**

scenario: you create ordinary linux user here
**useradd -m USER1**

USER1 is now an ordinary Linux user, and by default this linux user USER1 is mapped to SElinux unconfined_u USER1, and by default all created user will be under SElinux unconfined_u, even root user
check using this command
**semanage login -l**

when you decide to map ordinary linux USER1 to SElinux sysadm_u user you will not be able to ssh to USER1.
**semanage login -m -s sysadm_u -r s0 USER1**

USER1 is now mapped to SELinux sysadm_u user, this has prevented me from SSH utility

how to fix the problem?
well, try to map linux user "USER1" to SELinux user "user_u", this would actually solve the problem

don't map users to SElinux sysadm_u

Answer (score 0):

Open the ssh.config file on the target server with the below command:

> sudo nano /etc/ssh/ssh.config

Add the below lines at the end of that file

> ClientAliveInterval 300
>
> ClientAliveCountMax 2

press Ctrl+o and enter.

> sudo reboot

This acutally worked for me. I was in the same situation. Tried this and that but just follow these steps. Only this.
I hope it will work for you too.

Answer (score 0):

I kept getting this error when connecting remotely to a server based in my office. We do not use a VPN so all external connections go through a proxy server. The IT department had provided the following SSH configuration entry, which I copied straight into my `~/.ssh/config`:

```
Host xx.xx.xx.xx
  ProxyCommand ssh username@proxyserver exec netcat -w 5 %h %p
```

I don't know why they included the `-w 5` because that sets a very short timeout of 5 seconds of inactivity before the connection is broken. Removing or increasing the `-w` parameter eliminates the issue (as does switching to just `ProxyJump username@proxyserver`, which is what IT is now recommending).